# while testing the dropdown in the phptravels site with selenium python i came across the issue.that i cannot select the value from dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The values are only loaded when we search with more than 3 keywords.

[image]
please help me to find a solution - my code is the following...

```
depart = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'select2-choice select2-default')]")
depart.click()
depart.select_by_value('Delhi Indira Gandhi Intl (DEL)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here code you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#...
fromPlace = "Delhi Indira Gandhi"

#If will not enter text to FROM field, uncomment click code below 
#driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#s2id_location_from a').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen12').send_keys(fromPlace)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='select2-result-label' and contains(.,'"+ fromPlace +"')]"))).click()
```

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_id('s2id_autogen12').send_keys(fromPlace)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'` This is the error i got while execute.

Comment: It should be find_element_by_id

Comment: Still got this error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"s2id_autogen12"}`